# What is actually meant when it is said Scalar is invariant?

Tags: classical-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity, invariants

As far as i know a quantity is called invariant if it satisfies some specific transformations.
Now,Suppose a body is moving with velocity $\vec{v}$ as measured from the lab frame.Its non-relativistic kinetic energy is therefore, $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$,which is a scalar and must be invariant.But in an inertial frame which moves with the body with same velocity $\vec{v}$,the kinetic energy is $0$.The kinetic energy appears to be frame dependent then how can it be invariant?Then,what is actually meant by "invariant"?

Comment: Invariant mean that if you transform the velocity to a neu coordinate system $\overrightarrow{v}\rightarrow R\overrightarrow{v}$ you get the same kinetic energy $T=\dfrac{1}{2}m\left( R\overrightarrow{v}\right) ^{T}\,\left( R\overrightarrow{v}\right) =\dfrac{1}{2}mv^{2}$

Answer (score 2):

When something is said to be “invariant”, it is critical to understand what [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) of transformations it is invariant *under*.

$\vec{v}^2$ *is* an invariant under the group of translations and rotations in three-dimensional Euclidean space, but is *not* an invariant under the group of [Galilean boosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation), which are the rotationless transformations to other inertial reference frames in uniform motion relative to the first.